# Is “a little” used literally in these sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I heard this when I was scrolling through Tik Tok:

> “I find myself losing just a little bit of my faith in humanity every day.”

^ Context: the speaker was commenting about police brutality.

I also saw an Instagram caption saying:

> “Here’s to loving myself a little more every day.”

^ Context: the speaker was telling her audience about self-love.

I don’t think “a little” is used literally here but I’m not sure. Could someone please explain this expression to me? What do people try to express when they use it in their sentences? Thank you.

Comment: I think you would have to ask the person who wrote them, but IMO "yes". Please see [**little by little**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/little_by_little) and [**bit by bit**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bit_by_bit).

Comment: 'A little' / 'a bit' / 'a little bit' are used as adverbs in this context and are synonymous. Are you confusing 'little' with its adjective use? Have a look at the link here: https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv203.shtml#:~:text=A%20little%2C%20a%20bit%20and,or%20no%20difference%20in%20meaning.

Answer (score 1):

**Little** in

> I find myself losing just a little bit of my faith in humanity every day.”

is an adjective modifying "bit" - it tells you how big the "bit" is: the bit is small/little

**a little** in

> “Here’s to loving myself a little more every day.” {a little} [more] is an adverbial quantifier = by a small amount [more] (More is a comparative adverb.)